# terraform substring handle

Tags: terraform, substring

I am trying to find a solution to use my VM name to find the correct OU path for domain joining. But I couldn't able to find the right answer.
My conditions are:

```
VMR1 = domou1
VMR2 = domou2
others = domou3
```

terraform code:

```
variable vm_name {
default = "VMR1001"
}
locals{
vmou = "${(substr("${var.vm_name}", 0, 4) == "VMR1") ? "domou1" : ((substr("${var.vm_name}", 0, 4) == "VMR2") ? "domou2" : "domou3")}"
}
```

This always giving me the "domou3" as an answer as the first condition is not getting resolved.

Comment: this works fine, double check if your file is saved or committed. Or you might not be looking in the right place

Comment: Thanks for saving my day! It's my bad. I was changing at wrong vm block in .tfvars file. Unfortunately terraform debugging is hard for beginners like me.